# не работает кодировка utf8_general_ci

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

[PHP MyAdmin,Apache] На сервере стоит кодировка utf8_general_ci, в редакторе php UTF-8, на локалке выводятся кракозябры. В чем причина? Все таблицы тоже в правильной кодировке.

```
    <?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect ('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'test_db');
    if( $connection == false )
    {
        echo 'Не удалось подключиться к базе данных!<br>';
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    } else
    {
        echo 'Работает подключение';
    }

?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это обсуждалось много раз, проверьте для начала BOM

Comment: Постараюсь найти и понять

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Маркер_последовательности_байтов
если это не оно - SET NAMES UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

```
$connection = mysqli_connect ('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'test_db');
$connection->set_charset("utf8");
```

Плюс в отдаваемой странице должен быть указан:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Так же в php.ini следует установить

```
default_charset="UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Кодировка должна быть UTF-8 без BOM

Comment: У меня как раз с BOM работает почему то,а без BOM нет.